# iOS Bottom navigation (home etc) in HTML5?

Tags: html, cordova

i have created a HTML5 application (test application, nothing fancy) and this is loaded in phonegap. Works fine. BUT... i want to expand it a bit, and have the standard IOS buttons "home, app, contact" on the bottom. Also some form of navigation at the top.

As the app i made is started in "app.html" i would like to create a "index.html" with the buttons and maybe some iframe for the "app.html" ?

Anyone got any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out jQuery Mobile [here](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Some html5 and javascript framework will help you to do this such as jquery mobile,sencha touch and jquery touch